# How to change the HTML file template on Aptana Studio 3 beta?

Tags: aptana

Aptana Studio 3 beta's HTML5 file template is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame 
       Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

  <title>new-file</title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="generator" content="Studio 3 http://aptana.com/" />
  <meta name="author" content="Wei Lou" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />

  <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <header>
      <h1>new-file</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <p><a href="/">Home</a></p>
      <p><a href="/contact">Contact</a></p>
    </nav>

    <div>

    </div>

    <footer>
     <p>&copy; Copyright 2011 by Wei Lou</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanna change it. But I cannot find way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The directions Ingo points to give a thorough explanation of how to create a new template from scratch. In this case, since you only want to modify an existing template, you might try the following.

1. Select Commands->HTML->Edit this bundle. This will create a new "HTML" project in your workspace.
2. Open the templates folder in the "HTML" project
3. Edit and save the html5.html file

Now when you create a new HTML template, it should use the copy of the html5.html file you edited. Of course, you can edit any of the other templates in that project as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! That's pretty useful!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to follow the instructions on creating a new template: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Creating+a+new+template. You can then modify the content however you like.