# Editing the default blank file

Tags: aptana

Hy there!

I've recently started to learn JS, and I was wondering if I can edit the default "Blank File" opened by aptana? Say I want a basic html frame to appear every time I make a blank file? This is what I'm aiming for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PULIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-trisct.dtd">
<html lang="EN" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type"; content="text/xml"; charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[


      //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you looking for eclipse settings?

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for customize you template in Aptana Studio, take a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534490/how-to-change-the-html-file-template-on-aptana-studio-3-beta)**.

Otherwise, if you are looking for customize your file in eclipse, you have to open:

```
Window -> Preferences
```

And then select:

```
Aptana -> Editor -> Templates
```

In this section you can customize whatever you need.